# How to feed live json onto php

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a web server url that generating json data. Data is refreshed every 5 sec.
It looks like this:

```
[{"key": 0, "value": 586},{"key": 1, "value": 509},{"key": 2, "value": 472},{"key": 3, "value": 458},{"key": 4, "value": 454},{"key": 5, "value": 436}]
```

I am able to display it in php like this:

1.

```
 <?php
        $url = 'http://16x.xxx.xxx.2xx:8180';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $data;
        ?>
```

Question, is how do I auto update this to capture all the values every 5 sec?

2. I am also trying to write to a mysql table.

Comment: <?php
        $url = 'http://16x.xxx.xxx.2xx:8180';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $data;
        ?>

Comment: Setup a cronjob with this php file every 5 seconds. Or If using this values in frontend, then call an AJAX in  setInterval function with 5 second intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that you run from the command line (CLI) with nohup that will read your data every X seconds and process it according to your needs.

example : nohup php /my/php/script.php &